# How can I update google analytics snippet in minima?

Tags: jekyll, minima

Google analytics has recently changed the code snippet that needs to be added to pages.
Minima theme still uses old template, which results in data loss. [Here is an open issue on github](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/561).

I assume I should be able to fix that issue by editing gem files locally.

I tried to  into gem folder on my machine(`` cp -R `echo "$(bundle info minima --path)/_*/"` . ``), modify code there and rebuild my website (with `bundle exec Jekyll build`), but that doesn't seem to help.

I am new to Jekyll/Ruby and would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM

> Customizing templates
>
> To override the default structure and style of minima, simply create
> the concerned directory at the root of your site, copy the file you
> wish to customize to that directory, and then edit the file. e.g., to
> override the _includes/head.html file to specify a custom style path,
> create an _includes directory, copy _includes/head.html from minima
> gem folder to /_includes and start editing that file.